# Audit failed for wanting to recommend deletion to an answer that reads like a joke solution

Tags: support, review-audits

So doing some review queue stuff a few minutes ago and I [came across this item](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/433285). The original question is about remotely shutting down a PC that has no apparent RDP connectivity. The answer I wanted to delete was basically recommending building a [Rube Goldberg contraption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine):

> Find an old computer with a CD-ROM drive. Install linux. Name it
>   HOMECOMPUTERSHUTDOWNROBOT. Find a plastic stick, about 2 inches long.
>   Superglue it to the CD-ROM door so that it sticks straight out from
>   the computer. Position the old computer so that the stick points at
>   the power button for the computer you want to shut down. Use old books
>   as necessary to prop the computer up to the needed height to do so.
>
> When you want to turn off the computer, SSH into
>   HOMECOMPUTERSHUTDOWNROBOT. In the terminal, use the `eject` command to
>   eject the CD drive. The plastic stick will push the power button of
>   the computer not supporting RDP and turn it off.

Okay this is a cute idea that shows a creative use of an ejectable optical drive mechanism. But come on? I failed an audit for saying this idea should be deleted?

The question has [a very good accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/971420/167207) as well as [a much higher ranked alternative answer](https://superuser.com/a/971432/167207). This joke answer was posted hours after those other answers and really adds not much.

Screenshot of the audit context here:

[image]

Comment: Are audits (semi?) automated? AFAICT it seems that the process here was: 1) joke answer voted up for humour 2) system selects that as a 'good quality answer' candidate due to high score 3) presented as audit 4) sad panda :-/ While irksome, [failing an occasional audit isn't a problem](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7357/461558) as such.

Comment: I quite agree- I've had a few irritating **STOP. YOU FAILED. GO TO JAIL. DO NOT PASS GO. DO NOT COLLECT $200.** for some audits I don't agree with; though I'll admit this one seems pretty egregious. Perhaps a diamond can moderate audit selections?

Comment: @JakeGould, I get them all the time.  Just roll with it.  Generally I find though that the majority of them require you to fail the post.  So if you were answering the audit questions randomly, you would be safer in being negative.

Comment: I'm surprised that only got 11 upvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already been mentioned several times in all the "failed audit" meta questions mods have no say in what questions go into audits.

*Technically* though, that is an actual valid workable answer to the question.  That there are other and better answers is irrelevant.

It sounds ludicrous, and it probably *was* meant as a joke but it is a solution that would probably work.  That makes it an actual answer.

Mods, while having a greater say in what happens on the site, are slightly constrained in how they can act.  Unanimously running rampage across the site deleting anything that we find is considered a "no-no".  We try, wherever possible, to act with the community consensus of what is acceptable on our site.

Just because someone doesn't like an answer or thinks an answer it "too silly" or is "missing the point" does not make that answer any less valid than any of the other answers and mods have to keep that in mind when dealing with flags.

If you want that answer gone from the site then I would recommend asking a meta-question specifically asking whether we should allow these types of answers.  Generally though (and I know this is regarding questions) [we don't hate fun](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3332/should-humorous-funny-questions-be-deleted-from-super-user/3337#3337).